# How to redirect to a page with specific tab(or pill) active when a div is clicked

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have this div tag which is clickabe. I want to open selectorders page with service tab open when i click on class"1st" div.I am using bootstrap4 and jquery for the following.

I have tried addClass and removeClass but nothing works.

select.php

```
<div class="col-sm ty 1st">
<p style="margin-bottom:7px;"><span>Servicing</span></p>
<img src="../images/service.png">
</div>
<div class="col-sm ty 1st">
<p style="margin-bottom:7px;"><span>Servicing</span></p>
<img src="../images/service.png">
</div>
<div class="col-sm ty 2nd">
<p style="margin-bottom:7px;"><span>Repairing</span></p>
<img src="../images/repair.png">
</div>
```

selectorder.php

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link service" data-toggle="pill" 
href="#serv">Servicing</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link repair" data-toggle="pill" 
href="#repair">Repairing</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="serv" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
<div class="media border sec p-3">
<div class="media-body">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ndns nznc</p>  
</div>      
</div>
</div>

 <div id="repair" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
 <h3>Menu 1</h3>
 <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
 laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

jquery.js

```
$(".1st").click(function(){
window.location.href="../main/selectorders.php"; 
$(".active").removeClass("active");
$(".service").addClass("active").show();
})
```

Comment: You say you're doing this in php but I fail to see "php". That php you say you have, has no php directives, just HTML.

Comment: Please refine your question following these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have not displayed php code here as it was not necessary. Follwing problem can be solved with jquery i believe.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that JS and jQuery do not maintain application state over page requests, so you need to figure out either a) how to provide your JS/jQuery code via PHP or b) use PHP code to add a class on the link item which should be active given the route/state of your application.

This is one of the reasons people use JS and PHP frameworks. If you are using a framework please notate that so someone can further help you.